# Can't adjust table decently

Tags: tables, adjustbox

The following LaTeX code generates a table, but it surpasses the limits of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Identificador de contig & Tamanho do contig (bp) & Melhor hit (organismo) & e-value & Identidade (\%) & Tamanho do alinhamento (bp) (\% do tamanho do contig) & Algoritmo usado \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've tried to resize the table in order to fit it on the page, but the table went too small:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth,center=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Identificador de contig & Tamanho do contig (bp) & Melhor hit (organismo) & e-value & Identidade (\%) & Tamanho do alinhamento (bp) (\% do tamanho do contig) & Algoritmo usado \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there a simple way that my table can be fit decently?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!Never use `\adjustbox` for tables. It leads to inconsistent font sizes. This being said, could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the code! Sorry for not posting a full compilable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is to long column headers. did they really need to be so long? one solution is break headers texts into more line. for example as follows:

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

for this is used the macro `makecell` from the package of the same name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}%[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\thead{Identificador\\ de contig}
    &   \thead{Tamanho do\\ contig (bp)}
        &   \thead{Melhor hit\\ (organismo)}
            &    \thead{e-value}
                &   \thead{Identidade\\ (\%)}
                    &   \thead{Tamanho do\\ alinhamento (bp)\\ (\% do tamanho do contig)}
                        &   \thead{Algoritmo\\ usado}    \\
    \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you switch from `tabular` to `tabularx`, with a centered version of the `X` column type. That way, you'll get automatic line breaking in the header cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % is 'portuguese' correct
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{C|}}
\hline
Identificador de contig & Tamanho do contig (bp) & Melhor hit (organismo) & 
e-value & Identidade (\%) & Tamanho do alinhamento (bp) (\% do tamanho do contig) & 
Algoritmo usado \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip! And yes, 'portuguese' is correct haha.